# Why is the thermosphere more dense than the mesosphere or stratusphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, density, gas

According to my environmental science textbook and various sources on the web, the thermosphere has the second highest density of any part of the atmosphere. It falls only behind the troposphere which can be explained as the most dense because the force of gravity holds gas particles there.

But here is where I get lost,

The thermosphere is located at a higher altitude than the stratosphere or mesosphere and has a higher temperature. It collects most of the thermal energy released in radiation from the sun. The thermosphere is more dense than the two layers directly below it (stratosphere and mesosphere.) But why is that?

Pressure and temperature would be higher, but those shouldn't effect density. If density is mass/volume, then shouldn't the density be lower in the hottest part of the atmosphere due to Charles' Law?

I can't really find any reason why it would be more dense other than this theory from Einstein that adding thermal energy to a gas particle would increase its mass. (can someone explain why this would be, I get increasing its kinetic energy but thats cause of speed increase, not mass.)

Attached is a graph detailing temperature, density, and pressure in the different altitudes, I've been turning about this for a few hours and any input is greatly appreciated!! :)

[image]

Comment: Sources needed; those sources that do indeed say that "the thermosphere has the second highest density of any part of the atmosphere" are flat-out wrong. Perhaps they are writing about temperature and you misread? Satellites in low Earth orbit (LEO) orbit in the thermosphere. The density is so low in the thermosphere that while atmospheric drag is present, it only makes them lose altitude slowly. Once a satellite's orbit has decayed so that perigee is 80 to 100 km (the upper mesosphere) the satellite is literally toast due to the roughly exponential increase in density with reduced altitude.